# How to read specific cell in DataFrame and write into it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following Dataframe:

```
df:
   00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Also  I have a lot of INT-Pairs - which represent a specific row and column in this DF

for example:

```
3,5---
6,2---
3,1--- 
2,3---
3,1---
```

the number of matches should be counted in the DataFrame, so after reading all the pairs the DF should look like this:

```
df:
   00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
3   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the way you are indexing is backwards, you want `row` then `column`:

**`for loop`** with **`iloc`**

```
pairs = [(5, 3), (2, 6), (1, 3), (3, 2), (1, 3)]

for pair in pairs:
    df.iloc[pair] += 1

# Result

   00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
3   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```